# Exportação de conteúdo do BD para uma tabela WORD

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-word

Bom, eu estava fazendo um trabalho e me deparei com essa situação:
Preciso exportar certo conteúdo para o Word, porém conteúdo este que deve estar em uma tabela do mesmo.
Como eu poderia fazer um While para criar as Linhas e Colunas automaticamente dentro do próprio `C#` ?

Por enquanto meu Select está assim

```
  "SELECT ID_PRODUTO AS 'ID', NOME AS 'NOME', QTD AS 'QUANTIDADE',
   VLR_UNIT AS 'VALOR UNITÁRIO' 
   FROM ESTOQUE"
```

Ele me retorna dados que resultariam em 8 Linhas de 4 Colunas cada.

Comment: Apresente o código C# onde você está fazendo essa consulta e criando o documento do Word